# Laravel model count only one result for id

Tags: php, laravel

i have a problem with this query:

```
$winecount=App\Models\OrderProduct::where('id_order',$item->id_order)->where('id_wine',$item->id_wine)->groupBy('id_wine')->count();
```

i get:

| id_order | id_wine |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 2 |

i want to get instead:

| id_wine | qty |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 |
| 2 | 3 |

how can I modify the query so that I have the count for each "id_wine"?

for clarity this is my view:

```
Bottiglie ordinate:

Keane Nieves x10

Keane Nieves x10

Keane Nieves x10

Lucy Rasmussen x10

Lucy Rasmussen x10

Lucy Rasmussen x10

Nayda Duncan x10

Nayda Duncan x10

Nayda Duncan x10

Ruth Boyd x10

Ruth Boyd x10

Ruth Boyd x10
```

instead of:

```
Bottiglie ordinate:

Keane Nieves x30

Lucy Rasmussen x30

Nayda Duncan x30

Ruth Boyd x30
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You count the entire result. but you have to count the grouped by parts.
That query would help you:

```php
$user_info = DB::table('order_products')
                 ->select('id_wine', DB::raw('count(*) as qty'))
                 ->groupBy('id_wine')
                 ->get();
```

**sugested by Question Owner**

```
$winecount = OrderProduct::selectRaw('count(*) as qty')
  ->groupBy('id_wine')
  ->get();
```

Comment: thanks for to suggest. i prefer use model eloquent -> `$winecount=OrderProduct::selectRaw('count(*) as qty')->groupBy('id_wine')->get();`

Comment: @alessioscionti Welcome! And it helps? You got the counts by wine_id? Maybe you have to made a join to the wine names

Comment: Yes, multiple ways to do that. If you use DB then you have to import the DB in your class. The your approach is also good!

Comment: i have the wine count, but i can't merge the name of the wines, only the id

Comment: I solved it by inserting an additional selectRaw: `$winecount=OrderProduct::where('id_order',$key->id_order)->selectRaw('count(*) as qty',)->selectRaw('id_wine as id_wine')->groupBy('id_wine')->get();`